Daughter might be showing signs of ASD?
I have a lovely DD who today just turned 21 months and I am pretty sure she has some ASD traits.
Positive

She can say up to 100 words.
She can do pointing, waves and claps, and pretend playing.
She has always brought us toys / books etc, follow commands to an extent like "it's bath time."
She is also a good sleeper, she can self settle after the bottle.
She imitates everything.
She has good joint attention and always look where I am pointing.
She can put two words together.
She is very engaging and saying hello and smiling to people who engage with her.
She can identify animals on books and tv correctly .
She understands simple commands like "Time to go out," "bath time," "get your shoes," "shut the door," "pick it up," or "get me baby dolly"
She can tell me when she does a "poo"
She can answer the questions "What’s that?" and "Where is dolly?"
She is very affectionate.

Reason to worry:

She tenses up and tippy toes when excited since she was 14 months.

She rotates her wrists and ankles when excited, always done. It’s what worries me most.

Occasionally she does side glancing when turning her head to look at something behind her shoulders.

She doesn’t answer simple questions like "Do you want milk?"

She has an extraordinary memory.


My HV (health visitor, a nurse who comes to check up on the child), and doctor don’t see a reason to assess her. Now I understand that would be close to impossible getting a diagnosis or assessment based on this but was wondering if any of your kids had this presentation .
Many thanks ☺️

Hi and welcome. This would be a bit easier to understand if you don't use abbreviations (ASD, DD, HV, GP). This being said, almost everything of what you describe sound perfectly normal to me. Especially positive 8 is about as non-autistic as it gets. But we can't really dispense medical advise here and you need to work with your pediatrician . If you don't trust them, get a second or third opinion. If 2 or more doctors say "she is perfectly fine", than you really don't need to worry. Enjoy your daughter!

Not "a bit easier", it is almost impossible to understand as I have no idea at all what DD could be (daughter, something?), I am guessing ASD is probably autistic spectrum disorder, HV is beyond me, and GP stands for general practitioner, a term not very widely used outside the United Kingdom. Please avoid using these things as they are often confusing. As an anectodal aside, my 20 year old nephew who has neither been diagnosed with "ASD" nor has ever given any indication he might need a diagnosis, rotates his wrists when happy to this very day and did so from infancy.

How are these reasons to worry? What are you worried about? Wtf is a DD? Please be more specific! Thanks :)

It's not impossible to get a diagnosis; screening for autism in the US starts at 18 months. It is impossible, however, to tell over the internet. Look at milestons for toddlers and see if she's behind. If she's not, trust your GP or ask to have her tested. Start to worry if she regresses, especially in her speech. I'm voting to close because diagnosis is off topic.

The unusual postures when excited might be a symptom of dyspraxia (aka Developmental Co-ordination Disorder).  https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/developmental-coordination-disorder-dyspraxia/symptoms/ But as others have said, you should absolutely not take the advice of randoms on the Internet over qualified medical practitioners.

Regardless of what diagnosis your child does or does not get, I suggest you carefully consider the mindset that leads you to label your categories the way you did, because you basically said that "positive = not autistic-like", and that is kind of problematic.  If you'd labeled your first category something like "developmentally typical" that would have been a little less value-laden.

@swbarnes2 - That is a way-too-politically-correcty comment. The OP implied positive correctly: we physicians feel positively optimistis when normal milestones are reached. We parents are positively charmed by the things our kids do. We worry endlessly about everything. If you would like to have an autistic child, go for it. If you're unsuccessful at making one, adopt one. Not everyone thinks it's a bowl of cherries, so please back off and let the OP express herself as she finds able/easiest/honest.

@terdon HV = Health Visitor, a nurse in the UK who periodically checks on children under 5 at their homes. https://www.healthcareers.nhs.uk/explore-roles/public-health/roles-public-health/health-visitor
